# Show Group ID with two querys

Tags: php

I hope that you can help me :)

```
Table client_access:

+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | group_id | email  | firstname | lastname |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1  |    2     | e@ss.s | john      | terry    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2  |    1     | b@ss.s | Marie     |  joli    |
+-----------------------------------------------+

Table client_group:

+-----------------------------------------------+
| id |    name         | descri     | color     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1  |    Gooduser     | good users | #000      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2  |    Baduser      | bad users  | #ff0      | 
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I want Print:

```
Client: John terry 
Group: baduser
Color: #ff0
```

Maybe someone can help you to create this query?

Comment: Come on this is a simple JOIN,try something.http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Maybe someone can help me? :)

Answer (score -1):

I did :)

```
SELECT *, (SELECT name FROM client_group WHERE id=o.group_id) AS gname, (SELECT color FROM client_group WHERE id=o.group_id) AS gcolor, (SELECT id FROM hb_client_access WHERE id=o.id) AS guser FROM  client_access AS o WHERE id='".$userid."' LIMIT 1
```

Thank for all